# Error Bound using Stirling's approximation

Tags: numerical-methods, standard-error

Using Stirling's formula, how can we bound the absolute error of $$e^x-\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{x^n}{n!}$$ on the interval $|x|\leq R$ where $R\leq N/2e$

Answer (score 3):

Use the upper bound by geometric series
$$
\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty\frac{|x|^n}{n!}\le\frac{|x|^{N+1}}{(N+1)!}\cdot\frac1{1-\frac{|x|}{N+2}}
$$
or use the Taylor expansion remainder term
$$
e^{\theta x}\cdot\frac{x^{N+1}}{(N+1)!}
$$
for some $\theta\in (0,1)$.

Comment: Thank you. How does this provide a bound?

Comment: Insert the Stirling approximation for $(N+1)!$ and apply the given bounds or similar ones to $\left(\dfrac{|x|e}{N+1}\right)^{N+1}$.